# Should response data be entirely reflected on the client side?

Tags: json, parsing, architecture, client, software-design

Recently I was involved in a discussion regarding parsing response data from a REST API.

My point was that only client necessary data should be parsed from JSON object. In my opinion there's no obvious reason to clutter a client object with information not needed for it's use case.

Other opinion stated that we should parse the response 1:1 so that it reflects received data entirely and than create some intermediate object for client usage only with the sufficient properties. In this case I don't see any obvious reason how this approach would benefit anything.

Are there any best practices regarding this topic? What are the pros/cons regarding each solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "parsed" form a JSON object, what do you mean?  JSON is an object representation... Are you making another object that looks like the JSON object for some reason but isn't the one generated by JSON.parse()?

Assuming that is what you are doing, then you should make that new object as focused as possible, perhaps as a ViewModel.  There would be little point in creating ANOTHER JavaScript object that looks just like the results of JSON.parse().

If this is not what you are trying to accomplish, then I likely need more details to comment.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have an iOS application written in Swift. In order to access the response content from a Swift object, the JSON properties are mapped into Swift object properties. My question was if Swift object should contain all properties that are available in JSON, or only the ones that are needed later for use in application?

Comment: I would still limit my mapping as much as possible.  The less coupling you have between layers the better off you are.  This is obviously not the case if you will reuse this model in multiple contexts.  But if you are looking at a single use-case, then yes, you should not map properties that you won't be using in your context.  It will only increase the fragility of your application.